# Problem 48 in A First Course in Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have an issue with problem 48 Chapter 2, page 51 in Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability (9th edition). The problem is as follows, Given 20 people, what is the probability that among the 12 months in the year, there are 4 months containing exactly 2 birthdays and 4 containing exactly 3 birthdays?

So originally I computed $$\dfrac{\dbinom{12}{4,4,4}\dbinom{20}{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}}{12^{20}}\approx.00106$$ Which matches other peoples solutions and the older edition's (8 and lower) solution in the back of the book (it is definitely the same problem). However, the 9th edition has another solution of .01697, which I found to be using the same methodology as above but mixing the months that have 2 and 3 birthdays, ie $$\dfrac{\dbinom{12}{4,4,4}\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot \dbinom{20}{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}}{12^{20}}$$ My question is, which would be correct regardless if my reasoning may be flawed in the second, (ie maybe the computation is right but my reason is wrong), why would Ross update the problem with a different solution if the first was correct? Is this just a mistake in the update?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "mixing the months that have $2$ and $3$ birthdays"?

Comment: Can you please tell the page number.

Comment: @ABcDexter page 51

Comment: @joriki To be honest I'm not entirely sure, I was pulling my hair out to try and understand how the answer was .01697 as my reasoning for the first computation seemed to be correct to me. I started computing any strange idea I had, in this case I just thought, "oh maybe the non zero months have some sort of order that need to be counted" and so I tried it and it worked. Hence the sentence on my reasoning likely being flawed, regardless, empirically it seems Daishsan has shown that the first computation is correct, leading me to think it's an error in the solutions. There have been some before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you've worded the question, I would agree with your first answer. A simple Monte Carlo simulation backs this claim as well. For instance, after $10^8$ trials, my simple Java code gave a probability of $0.0010614$. Chernoff bounds suggest that a solution of $0.01697$ with this many trials is highly unlikely.

Comment: Ah empiricism is always nice. This is good news to me as I had a tough time explaining the second computation to myself. It seems there may be an error in the solutions, which I have found before in this text. Thanks for checking that helps a lot.